# Cython and constructors of classes

Tags: c++, python, constructor, cython, default-constructor

I have a problem with Cython usage of default constructors.

My C++ class Node is the following

`Node.h`

```
class Node
{
public:
    Node()
    { 
        std::cerr << "calling no arg constructor" << std::endl;
            w=0.0;
        d=0.0;
    }
    Node(double val, double val2);
    {
            std::cerr << "calling 2 args constructor" << std::endl;
        this->w=val;
        this->d=val2;
    }
private:
    double d,w;
}
```

is wrapped in Cython as follows

```
cdef extern from "Node.h":
    cdef cppclass Node:
        Node() except +
        Node(double val1, double val2) except +
        double d
        double w

cdef class pyNode:
    cdef Node *thisptr      # hold a C++ instance which we're wrapping

    def __cinit__(self):
        self.thisptr = new Node()

    def __cinit__(self, double val1, double val2):
        self.thisptr = new Node(val1,val2)

    def __dealloc__(self):
        del self.thisptr

    def __repr__(self):
        return "d=%s w=%s" % (self.thisptr.w, self.thisptr.w )
```

The Cython code compiles well, but in particular when called from Python

```
from pyNode import pyNode as Node
n=Node(1.0,2.0)
```

I get the expected `calling 2 args constructor` string,  but if I'm trying to declare a Node object from python using the "no-arguments" constructor (which should be correctly declared as `__cinit__(self)` I'm getting no output, this means that the no-argument constructor is not called!

How can I explicitly call it from the **cinit** method of the wrapped class?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue here is that you can't overload `__cinit__()` like that (as [only `cdef` functions can be overloaded](https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/enhancements-overloading)) - instead, have it take default values, then call the right thing as needed.

Edit: Essentially, you need to implement the function in a way closer to how you would in normal Python code, instead of using overloading:

```
def __cinit__(self, double val1=-1, double val2=-1): 
    if val1 == -1 or val2 == -1:
        self.thisptr = new Node()
    else:
        self.thisptr = new Node(val1,val2)
```

Naturally, this presumes `-1` is a value that isn't useful for the function, you could use another value, or if you need every value of a double to be valid, then you might need to remove the typing, taking a Python object so that you can use `None` as the default:

```
def __cinit__(self, val1=None, val2=None):
    if val1 is not None and val2 is not None:
        self.thisptr = new Node(val1, val2)
    else:
        self.thisptr = new Node()
```

Comment: So how do you suggest to modify the code? I didn't understand your suggestion, should I remove the __cinit__ and let cython declare it for me?

Comment: Note though that this does have the somewhat unpleasant side effect that `Node(5)` works and calls the two-arg constructor with `5, -1`; might want to check for that. And of course, based on the C++ code here using 0 as the default values (and then only ever calling the two-arg constructor) would have the same effect.

Comment: @Dougal Presuming that you will never change what the default constructor does. Edit: And added an ``or`` to ensure both values are set.

Comment: Thanks, now it's clear! Is this a kind of workaround or a wanted feature? (I work mainly in C++ so this kind of things look strange)

Comment: In Python, it doesn't make sense to overload functions (as types are not important, so there would be no differentiation except number of arguments, which is handled better by default values), so overloading doesn't exists. Cython adds this for ``cdef`` functions, but not for Python functions like ``__cinit__()``.

Comment: What if the `val1` and `val2` are not of the wanted type? How do I specify that they must be two `double` and not, for example, two lists?

Comment: You will get an exception at that point as it tries to convert the values for the c function.

Comment: What if I modify my function using `type(val1) is int and type(val2) is float`

Comment: @linello It wouldn't make a difference.

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: @RestInPeace They moved the wiki to github, updated.