# How to write C++ constructor of cython extension type?

Tags: cython

How do I modify the C++ class constructor that cython will generate from a Cython extension type that I've defined in a `.pyx` file wo that I don't incur the penalty of using `def __cinit__(self)`? Assume I am compiling to C++, not C.

What I would like to do is set the default values as I would in an initialization list in C++, and maybe run some code in the constructor without interacting with Python. It looks like the `__cinit__` method runs after the C++ class members are initialized and the C++ constructor finishes running.

In [this example](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html), it says

> Cython initializes C++ class attributes of a cdef class using the nullary constructor.

I assume this refers to the default constructor since the C++ constructor is a nullary constructor. I also assumes this happens with or without a `__cinit__` method.

> If the class you’re wrapping does not have a nullary constructor, you must store a pointer to the wrapped class and manually allocate and deallocate it. A convenient and safe place to do so is in the **cinit** and **dealloc** methods which are guaranteed to be called exactly once upon creation and deletion of the Python instance.

I have an existing class where I call `Py_XDECREF` on a member object in a loop inside of `__dealloc__`. This object holds pointers to Python objects. When I convert to C++ code, the annotated HTML shows no highlighted yellow text in the lines where the `__dealloc__` method is defined. This is interesting because `__dealloc__` is also defined using `def`.

When I try to initialize a member that is an instance of a Cython Extension that I defined (and did not create from wrapping C++ code), however, the `__cinit__` method is highlighted in yellow.

```
    def __cinit__(self):
        self._member = MyCyExt()
```

I'm wondering if it's because I can't initialize a Cython Extension Type in pure C++. I don't know why that would be the case since Cython calls the nullary constructor by default.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13201968/5670215) solves the problem, but it incurs the overhead I am trying to avoid. Is there a way to do this without incurring that overhead and actually writing the constructor itself in a `.pyx` file?

Comment: I think you may be getting confused. "Cython initializes C++ class attributes of a cdef class using the nullary constructor." This refers to external things written in C++ that you are trying to use in Cython. For example if your class stored a `std::vector` then the default constructor would be called for the `std::vector`

Comment: It _doesn't_ refer to Cython extension types (even if you're compiling the Cython code to C++). You should expect code that initializes those to generate a bit of yellow. Don't write too much into the yellow highlighting though: it's a useful tool but it's also very rough, and it's sometimes unavoidable

Comment: I was in the middle of writing this before your second comment:

I knew it did it for externally written classes, but if my pyx file is being converted to C++, then there's going to be a default constructor somewhere (if not explicitly in the generated C++ code, the compiler has to have some way of telling the computer [how] to construct the object). Is there any way to modify that from a pyx file?

Is the short answer, no, and also, it doesn't hurt that much?

Comment: Even if you convert to C++ the code is still a lot closer to C - it doesn't use C++ constructors, but uses `malloc` and then calls `__cinit__`. Second, the object that is actually stored for `self._member` is a `PyObject*` (a pointer, rather than storage built into your class). The pointer is just initialized to `NULL` and no Cython object is constructed until you ask it to be.

Comment: You can always inspect the code it generates to see what it's doing. It isn't very easy too follow but it is possible. But the short answer is "no and also isn't does hurt that much"